# Adding TUNE to android

Tags: android, android-layout, sdk

I add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

However, upon Sync, I get this message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> Error:
>   more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'You
>   can temporarily disable this error with
>   android.enforceUniquePackageName=falseHowever, this is temporary and
>   will be enforced in 1.0

Comment: Post your total `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> Error:
>   more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'You
>   can temporarily disable this error with
>   android.enforceUniquePackageName=falseHowever,

At first Post your Total `build.gradle`

You can use only one . You have `two same type` library .**Call One of them** . **Don't need both** .

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0' // Use this 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart** .